# How can I stop my script asking the same question?

Tags: javascript, debugging

I'm making this quiz, it grabs a question randomly in an Array then is suppose to check if the question is not already in the Array so it isn't asked again. But when I submit to continue playing it keeps asking the same question.

```
var Question = function(question, answerChoice, answerRight, congrats, woops) {
    this.question = question;
    this.answerChoice = answerChoice;
    this.answerRight = answerRight;
    this.congrats = congrats;
    this.woops = woops;
}

var questionOne = new Question("What is the capital of France?", "1: Paris, 2: London", 1, "Well done!", "Woops");
var questionTwo = new Question("Smoking kills?", "1: Yes, 2: No", 1, "Well done!", "Woops");
var questionThree = new Question("Is coke good for your health?", "1: Yes, 2: No", 2, "Well done!", "Woops");
var questionFour = new Question("Do birds fly?", "1: Yes, 2: No", 1, "Well done!", "Woops");
var questionFive = new Question("Is green a color", "1: Yes, 2: No", 1, "Well done!", "Woops");
var questionSix = new Question("Do cars have wheels?", "1: No, 2: Yes", 2, "Well done!", "Woops");

var quiz = [questionOne, questionTwo, questionThree, questionFour, questionFive, questionSix];
var randomQ = quiz[Math.floor(Math.random() * quiz.length)];
var checkPrevious = [];
var gameScore = [0];



function gameInit(randomQuestion) {


  if (checkPrevious.includes(randomQuestion) === randomQuestion) {
      gameInit(randomQ);
  } else {

  checkPrevious.push(randomQuestion);
  console.log(randomQuestion.question);
  console.log(randomQuestion.answerChoice);
  var answerPrompt = prompt("What is the right answer?");
  var answer = parseInt(answerPrompt);


  randomQuestion.answerRight === answer ? (console.log(randomQuestion.congrats), gameScore += 1, console.log(gameScore))  : console.log(randomQuestion.woops);
  var continueP = prompt("Carry on playing ? write y to continue. Otherwise type any other key.");


  if (continueP === "y") {
    gameInit(randomQ);

  } else {
      alert("Thanks for playing !")
  }


  }
}

gameInit(randomQ);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are not generating random number again when calling a `gameInit` again if the user presses 'y'. Generate it

```
if (continueP === "y") {
    randomQ=quiz[Math.floor(Math.random() * quiz.length)];
    gameInit(randomQ);

}
```

and also checking repetition, we have to check if it exists.If it exists regenerate the `randomQuestion`.If it doesn't exists then only push into `checkPrevious`.

```
if (checkPrevious.includes(randomQuestion)) {
    randomQ=quiz[Math.floor(Math.random() * quiz.length)];
    gameInit(randomQ);
  }
 else{
  checkPrevious.push(randomQ)
  ..other code
 }
```

```js
var Question = function(question, answerChoice, answerRight, congrats, woops) {
  this.question = question;
  this.answerChoice = answerChoice;
  this.answerRight = answerRight;
  this.congrats = congrats;
  this.woops = woops;
}

var questionOne = new Question("What is the capital of France?", "1: Paris, 2: London", 1, "Well done!", "Woops");
var questionTwo = new Question("Smoking kills?", "1: Yes, 2: No", 1, "Well done!", "Woops");
var questionThree = new Question("Is coke good for your health?", "1: Yes, 2: No", 2, "Well done!", "Woops");
var questionFour = new Question("Do birds fly?", "1: Yes, 2: No", 1, "Well done!", "Woops");
var questionFive = new Question("Is green a color", "1: Yes, 2: No", 1, "Well done!", "Woops");
var questionSix = new Question("Do cars have wheels?", "1: No, 2: Yes", 2, "Well done!", "Woops");

var quiz = [questionOne, questionTwo, questionThree, questionFour, questionFive, questionSix];
var randomQ = quiz[Math.floor(Math.random() * quiz.length)];
var checkPrevious = [];
var gameScore = [0];



function gameInit(randomQuestion) {
  if (checkPrevious.includes(randomQuestion)) {
    randomQ=quiz[Math.floor(Math.random() * quiz.length)];
    gameInit(randomQ);
  } else {
    checkPrevious.push(randomQuestion);
    console.log(randomQuestion.question);
    console.log(randomQuestion.answerChoice);
    var answerPrompt = prompt("What is the right answer?");
    var answer = parseInt(answerPrompt);
    randomQuestion.answerRight === answer ? (console.log(randomQuestion.congrats), gameScore += 1, console.log(gameScore)) : console.log(randomQuestion.woops);
    var continueP = prompt("Carry on playing ? write y to continue. Otherwise type any other key.");
    if (continueP === "y") {
      randomQ = quiz[Math.floor(Math.random() * quiz.length)];
      gameInit(randomQ);
    } else {
      alert("Thanks for playing !")
    }

  }
}

gameInit(randomQ);
```

Comment: Thanks! I have a question though, why doesn't it work if I am calling randomQ as it is in the code, and why can it still ask me the same question ?

Comment: because randomQ is reference to the same question and you are not updating it.Thats why it is asking the same question

Comment: How ? I never found the button.

Answer (score 0):

You can filter arrays

```js
function filter(arr1, arr2) {
  return arr1.filter(function(item) {
    return !arr2.includes(item); 
  })
}



function gameInit(randomQuestion) {
  checkPrevious.push(randomQuestion);


  if (checkPrevious.includes(randomQuestion) === randomQuestion) {
      console.log('checkPrevious')
      gameInit(randomQ);
  } else {
      console.log(randomQuestion.question);
      console.log(randomQuestion.answerChoice);
      var answerPrompt = prompt("What is the right answer?");
      var answer = parseInt(answerPrompt);
  
  
      randomQuestion.answerRight === answer ? (console.log(randomQuestion.congrats), gameScore += 1, console.log(gameScore))  : console.log(randomQuestion.woops);
      var continueP = prompt("Carry on playing ? write y to continue. Otherwise type any other key.");
  
      if (continueP === "y") {
        var filtered = filter(quiz, checkPrevious)
        randomQ=quiz[Math.floor(Math.random() * filtered.length)];
        gameInit(randomQ);
  
      } else {
        alert("Thanks for playing !")
      }
  }
}
```